# Автоматический запуск всех приложений в полноэкранном режиме linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint

как сделать так, чтобы любая программа всегда открывалась в полном окне? Стандартный оконный менеджер linux mint. Если такое невозможно, то как сделать то же для конкретного приложения(например, терминала)?

Comment: А тебе зачем? Хочешь сделать типа интернет киоска?

Comment: была програмка старая, которая по типу окна сортировала и раздвигала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то в стародавние времена, когда тайловые менеджеры ещё не были популярны, я использовал программу devilspie для этого.

```
(if
(is (application_name) "Терминал")
(start
(maximise)
)
)
```

без условия - для всех окон.

посмотри gdevilspie, devilspie, devilspie2, может winctl